# Load bootstrap icons locally

Tags: bootstrap-5

I am new to bootstrap and setting up all bootstrap in local server in my system.

So instead of linking online stylesheet I have linked with local server like below.

```
<link href="http://127.0.0.1/bootstrap-5.3.3-dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

And for linking script file I have linked like below

```
<script src="http://127.0.0.1/bootstrap-5.3.3-dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-MrcW6ZMFYlzcLA8Nl+NtUVF0sA7MsXsP1UyJoMp4YLEuNSfAP+JcXn/tWtIaxVXM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Till now It is working fine.

When it comes to use bootstrap icons, Bootstrap provides below link for using icons.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-icons@1.11.3/font/bootstrap-icons.min.css">
```

Now, I have downloaded the same css file and linking it like below.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://127.0.0.1/bootstrap-icons-1.11.3/font/bootstrap-icons.min.css">
```

Now, If I use Icon Font like below. It's not working, however if I use the same css through online it's working.

```
<i class="bi-alarm"></i>
```

I am wondering how can I achieve this using local server.

**Update-After Comment**

I am getting below error.

```
Access to font at 'http://127.0.0.1/bootstrap-icons-1.11.3/font/fonts/bootstrap-icons.woff2?dd67030699838ea613ee6dbda90effa6' from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
bootstrap-icons.woff2:1 
        
        
Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FAILED

index.html:1 Access to font at 'http://127.0.0.1/bootstrap-icons-1.11.3/font/fonts/bootstrap-icons.woff?dd67030699838ea613ee6dbda90effa6' from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
bootstrap-icons.woff:1 
        
        
 Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FAILED
```

Comment: any errors in the console that might suggest why "it's not working"?

Comment: @Claies, I have updated error  in the post.

Comment: So you have a CORS error.  There are TONS of posts here and other places regarding how to set CORS headers.  By the way, this is not an error caused by bootstrap; rather, this is an error caused by whatever server you are running (you never provided this information).

Comment: Why this error is occurring for icons related css only, not for other bootstrap css.

Comment: Font files are downloaded dynamically, unlike stylesheets.  The stylesheet has a **reference** to the font file, and the `class` tells the browser which icon to load from the font file.  When the font file is actually needed, it tries to download, but it cannot, because Localhost is not a valid location to download font files from, due to security vulnerabilities.  CORS stops the request.  This likely can't be done, without severely compromising the security of the web server.

Comment: It is just a local server not a production server.

Comment: Right, but the entire web is based on the concept of Client-Server communications.  The idea of running a server on the same machine as the browser doesn't change the browser's behavior.  The browser is being told to load the file from `127.0.0.1` which implies the file is stored on the local machine hard drive, which is a security vulnerability, so the browser sends `'null'` as the origin.  The browser has no reason to assume that for this particular request, you are ok with it doing something that is normally an exploit.

Comment: If this is something that you ***really*** need to do, you can probably find some information for whatever server you are running on your machine to accept `null` as a valid origin, but this would make your machine extremely vulnerable, and in the long run, wouldn't provide any benefit once the site is put into production anyway.  You are better off finding a way to publish a sane url for your local server, rather than localhost.

Comment: Thanks for all your advice. I got your point. I am not going to do this in production. My Issue has been resolved after setting cors.